# SQL Parse xml column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have very little experience with SQL Server. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a table with many rows. Every row contains a column named "Config". The data stored in the Config column is of the `xml` type. The xml structure looks like this:

```
<root>
 <path1>
  <path2>
   <path3>true</path3>
  </path2>
 </path1>
</root>
```

I am trying to go through every row in the table and find the percentage of `true` to `false` values of `<path3>`.

I looked at some SQL documentation and tried to use the `value()` function I am having difficulties extracting the XML data from the column:

```
select Config.value('(/root/path1/path2/path3)[1]','nvarchar(max)') from [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
```

Here is the result of my query:

[image: SQL query result after executing the above statement]

> I would like to query and extract data from the XML "Config" column of my table and aggregate that data into columns.

Comment: I assume you know how to find a percentage, so to find the rows you are looking for use ` WHERE Config LIKE '%<path3>true</path3>%'` (and, of course, you can find `false` values the same way.

Comment: What you have [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e580956f171914b50607868968fec4f)?

Comment: Does your xml use namespace prefixed tags? kind of `<x:path1>`

Comment: Try, set quoted_identified on, before you run the query.

Comment: @Serg No namespaced prefixed tags in the xml

Comment: Your code should work under setup you've described. Can you share more details on real code and data?

Comment: @Serg Apologies, as I said I am a beginner with SQL. After doing some digging, I learned that the <root> has a namespace xmlns="...".

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify [namespaces in the query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-2017) when xml is built with namespaces. For example

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (Config xml);
INSERT INTO tbl (Config)
VALUES ('<root xmlns="abc">
 <path1>
  <path2>
   <path3>true</path3>
  </path2>
 </path1>
</root>') ;
```

Then

```
with xmlnamespaces (DEFAULT 'abc')
select Config.value('(/root/path1/path2/path3)[1]','nvarchar(max)') path3Txt
from tbl;
```

or explicit specification

```
with xmlnamespaces ('abc' as x)
select Config.value('(/x:root/x:path1/x:path2/x:path3)[1]','nvarchar(max)') path3Txt
from tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use CROSS APPLY. Check it out.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start

    DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, [Config] XML);
    INSERT INTO  @tbl
    VALUES (N'<root>
        <path1>
            <path2>
                <path3>true</path3>
            </path2>
        </path1>
    </root>')
    , (N'<root>
        <path1>
            <path2>
                <path3>false</path3>
            </path2>
        </path1>
    </root>');
    -- DDL and sample data population, end

    ;WITH rs AS
    (
       SELECT ID
          , col.value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS Result
        FROM @tbl tbl
          CROSS APPLY tbl.[Config].nodes('/root/path1/path2/path3') AS tab(col)
    )
    SELECT * FROM rs;
```